# Analysing 3D image FFT

Tags: image-processing, fft

I'm looking for a way to visually inspect the amplitude of frequency components in a 3D image that I have taken the fftn of in matlab. Does anyone have any idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually by analyzing the 2D slices of the 3D array.